# Why am I getting undefined symbol 'sprintf' in CodeVisionAVR using C language?

Tags: c, printf, undefined, lcd, codevisionavr

I'm coding in CodeVision AVR using C, I want to count from 0 to 100 (Counter) and then display it on a LCD in Proteus. While choosing "Build All" in CodeVision, I get this error. I have no clue why.

> undefined symbol 'sprintf'

The code:

```
#include <mega16.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <alcd.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    char buffer[10];
    lcd_init(16);
    while(1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
            lcd_clear();
            lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
            sprintf(buffer, "Time=%2d", i);
            lcd_putsf(buffer);
            delay_ms(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `#include <string.h>` ?

Comment: Your C implementation may or may not come with this function. It is a [freestanding implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding) geared towards small embedded devices, so most of the standard library could be omitted.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. typically , if sprintf is omitted then `stdio.h` would not be provided at all (and conversely, if `stdio.h` is provided then it would typically contain the standard functions normally provided by that header).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure that you have `#include <stdio.h>`

Also use `lcd_puts(buffer);` instead of `lcd_putsf(buffer);`

`lcd_putsf()` is the flash version of the lcd printing function. The way that you declared your character array, it is in ram and not flash, so you must use the other lcd printing function.

Comment: now I'm getting this error: function argument #1 of type 'unsigned char[10]' is incompatible with required parameter of type 'flash unsigned char *'

Comment: @fzsdi can you try using `lcd_puts(buffer);` instead of `lcd_putsf(buffer);`

Comment: @fzsdi did the development environment come with documentation? It should explain about flash memory versus RAM and so on

Comment: @fzsdi it is a ram vs flash issue. The way you declared the char array, it is stored in ram and not flash. The other printing function can only print flash variables.